# Scan WhatsApp QR code from device with broken screen to access WhatsApp Web

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, broken-screen, screen-mirroring

I need to get a bunch of WhatsApp contacts off my phone. However, I can't see anything on the screen. The phone still works. I tried to get it into debugging through USB mode but I can't see anything and is pretty much impossible.

I need a way to either mirror the phone to PC without being able to interact with the device or retrieve all my WhatsApp contacts via USB.

Answer (score 0):

There is an application through which you can control the screen over **USB** and **adb** called **ADB control**. Follow the link to install and use it. Then you backup contacts to your phone/google account once you have control.

Source: http://marian.schedenig.name/2014/07/03/remote-control-your-android-phone-through-adb/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have USB debugging enabled on your device?

[Droid@Screen](http://droid-at-screen.org/) allows seeing the screen output and also interacting.

Though it's slow but could help you out.

Comment: thats the issue i cant activate debugging through usb without being able to see what im doing. i tried a chrome app called Vysor, it doesnt pickup my phone even when plugged into usb.